# Proof Verification- Prove that $(a+b,a-b) \geq (a,b)$ for any two integers.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm

I came across this question while solving the book Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College mathematics. Please check if the proof that I have done is correct. (I am familiar with only basic number theory including basic theory of primes and modular arithmetic.)

I believe that I might have made some mistake in reasoning while proving that $bx-ay\geq 0$

Proof:

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $a$ and $b$ are both positive with $a\geq b \gt 0$

Since GCD can be written as linear combination of the two integers,

$$(a,b) = ax + by$$

We know that $(a,b) \leq b \leq a$
Which implies that either $x$ or $y$ is is negative.

We can assume that $y$ is negative. This implies $bx-ay\geq 0$. (Conversely if $x$ is negative then $ay-bx \geq 0$ )

Now,

$$ax + by = (a,b)$$
$$\Rightarrow ax + by + bx - ay \geq (a,b)$$
$$\Rightarrow (a+b)x + (b-a)y \geq (a,b)$$
$$\Rightarrow (a+b)x + (-y)(a-b) \geq (a,b)$$
$$\Rightarrow (a+b, a- b) \geq (a,b)$$

QED.

Comment: Your proof only shows that **some** linear combination of $a+b$ and $a-b$ is greater than or equal to $\gcd(a,b)$. It doesn't necessarily imply that $\gcd(a+b,a-b) \geq \gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected there was some mistake in the reasoning. If I want this question answered do I need to ask another question? Because I have no idea what to do and I am unable to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d=\gcd(a+b,a-b)$ and $\gcd(a,b)=e$.

$e$ must divide the sum and the difference of $a$ and $b$. This means that  $e \mid a+b$ and $e \mid a-b$. Thus $e$ is a common divisor of $a+b$ and $a-b$. Thus $e \mid \gcd(a+b, a-b)=d$. Thus

$$e \leq d.$$

*Your question is answered.*

However one can do a bit more:

Furthermore, $d \mid a+b$ and $d \mid a-b$. Then  $d \mid 2a$ and $d \mid 2b$. Thus $d$ is a common divisor of $2a$ and $2b$. Consequently, $d \mid \gcd(2a,2b)$. But $\gcd(2a,2b)=2\gcd(a,b)=2e$. Thus,
$$d \mid 2e \implies d \leq 2e.$$

So we can say
$$ e \leq d \leq 2e.$$

Comment: I am unsure of what you exactly proved. Did you really prove that the gcd of $a-b,a+b$ is always the double of the gcd of $a,b$? What happens when, say, $a=3, b=12$?

Comment: $d | \gcd(2a,2b)$ doesn’t imply that $d = \gcd(2a,2b)$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error. I had typed some stuff which got deleted by mistake and I didn’t realize that. I have fixed it. Let me know if something is missing.